# can SQLSRV32.DLL broker a TLS 1.2 handshake?

Tags: sql-server-2016, tls-1.2

Are there updates to SQLSRV32.DLL driver to support TLS 1.2? Version 10.00.18362 seems to broker a successful #TLS 1.2 handshake to #SQLServer 2016

https://sqlvandalism.com/2017/03/22/what-client-provider-am-i-using-to-connect-to-sql-server/ (near the end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLSRV32.DLL is the old SQL Server ODBC driver that's part of Windows.

In October 2020, Windows finally dusted off the source code for the built-in ODBC and OleDb SQL Server drivers and updated them to support TLS 1.2.  See [KB4580390](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/october-20-2020-kb4580390-os-build-17763-1554-preview-ac4799c9-838f-8665-a968-0f19b6cb1049).

Comment: Thank you David. Is is accurate to say that the SQLSRV32.DLL is no longer deprecated?

Comment: The changes announced in KB4580390 don't comment on data access protocol (sys.dm_exec_connections.protocol_version) and interface TDS protocol (sys.dm_exec_sessions.client_version). Using SQLSRV32.DLL to connect from a client, SQL Server 2016 reports these two values as "SQL Server 2000 SP1". Given KB4580390, are the reported values correct?

Comment: It was never technically deprecated.  Just old.  And it’s still a client from the SQL 2000 era.  But it’s supported but not being actively enhanced.  The new ODBC driver is still recommended. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15